# Trying to create a production Next build, but it is erroring out

Tags: javascript, reactjs, next.js, expo

I am getting the following error in NextJS 12, when I am trying to build it with Expo (which is a rare, but supported use-case):

```
info  - Creating an optimized production build
info  - Compiled successfully
info  - Collecting page data .node:internal/process/promises:279
            triggerUncaughtException(err, true /* fromPromise */);
            ^

/Users/myName/Desktop/Projects/AppName/Frontend/Next/node_modules/expo-modules-core/build/index.js:1
import { DeviceEventEmitter } from 'react-native';
^^^^^^

SyntaxError: Cannot use import statement outside a module
    at Object.compileFunction (node:vm:360:18)
    at wrapSafe (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:1084:15)
    at Module._compile (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:1119:27)
    at Object.Module._extensions..js (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:1209:10)
    at Module.load (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:1033:32)
    at Function.Module._load (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:868:12)
    at Module.require (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:1057:19)
    at require (node:internal/modules/cjs/helpers:103:18)
    at Object.21968 (/Users/myName/Desktop/Projects/AppName/Frontend/Next/apps/next/.next/server/pages/_app.js:1232:18)
    at __webpack_require__ (/Users/myName/Desktop/Projects/AppName/Frontend/Next/apps/next/.next/server/webpack-runtime.js:25:43) {
  type: 'SyntaxError'
}
```

This is my next.config.js:

```
/** @type {import('next').NextConfig} */

const { withNativebase } = require('@native-base/next-adapter');
const withImages = require('next-images');
const { withExpo } = require('@expo/next-adapter');
const withFonts = require('next-fonts');

module.exports = withNativebase({
  dependencies: [
    '@expo/next-adapter',
    'next-images',
    'next-fonts',
    'react-native-vector-icons',
    'react-native-vector-icons-for-web',
    'solito',
    'app',
    '@native-base/icons',
  ],
  plugins: [
    [withFonts, { projectRoot: __dirname }],
    withImages,
    [withExpo, { projectRoot: __dirname }],
  ],
  reactStrictMode: true,
  images: {
    domains: ['localhost'],
  },
  nextConfig: {
    typescript: {
      ignoreBuildErrors: true,
    },
    eslint: {
      ignoreDuringBuilds: true,
    },
    images: {
      disableStaticImages: true,
    },
    projectRoot: __dirname,
    reactStrictMode: true,
    webpack: (config, options) => {
      config.module.rules.map((rule) => {
        if (rule.test !== undefined && rule.test.source.includes('|svg|')) {
          rule.test = new RegExp(rule.test.source.replace('|svg|', '|'));
        }
      });

      config.module.rules.push({
        test: /\.ttf$/,
        loader: 'url-loader',
      });
      config.module.rules.push({
        test: /\.otf$/,
        loader: 'url-loader',
      });
      config.module.rules.push({
        test: /\.svg$/,
        use: ['@svgr/webpack'],
      });
      config.module.rules.push({
        test: /\.mp4$/,
        use: [
          {
            loader: 'url-loader',
          },
        ],
      });
      config.module.rules.push({
        test: /\.html$/,
        loader: 'html-loader',
      });
      config.resolve.alias = {
        ...(config.resolve.alias || {}),
        'react-native$': 'react-native-web',
        '@expo/vector-icons': 'react-native-vector-icons',
      };
      config.resolve.extensions = [
        '.web.js',
        '.web.ts',
        '.web.tsx',
        ...config.resolve.extensions,
      ];

      return config;
    },
  },
});
```

I have also tried using the nextJS transpiler (withTM), but that just broke all of my fonts and a bunch of other code.

I have a very similar setup working on another site, and so I am wondering what is breaking this - the error itself isn't super clear.

I feel like I am missing something, and the error isn't super clear on what exactly is wrong.

This is just an initial test for a migration to NextJS, so I've disabled things like type checking and others, I am just trying to get the thing to compile, and failing even at that

Comment: Next 13 has support for `transpileModules` but you are on 12 so can use the `next-transpile-modules` package.